# How to iterate json object structure to get only names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I have the following json object, how can I get/loop only to get the names values ?

```
var jsonobject = {
    "jsontest": [{
        "name": "firstnamevalue",
        "firstkey": "firstvalue"

    }, {
        "name": "secondnamevalue",
        "secondkey": "secondvalue",
        "thirdkey": false
    }, {
        "name": "thirdnamevalue",
        "fourthkey": null
    }],
    "fifthkey": "testvalues"
}
```

I need only name values, like: `firstnamevalue, secondnamevalue, thirdnamevalue` on my alert message ? Please let me know and thanks in advance.

Comment: You can easily use a simple for loop, as `jsonobject.jsontest` is an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use javascript `map` method to get the array  values based on your requirement.

```
  var results = jsonobject.jsontest.map(function(item,index){
     return item["name"];

    })
    results //
["firstnamevalue", "secondnamevalue", "thirdnamevalue"]
```

ES2015 with fat arrow (ES6)

```
jsonobject.jsontest.map((item,index)=> item["name"])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use underscore or lodash.
It can be done like:

```
_.pluck(jsonObject.jsonTest, 'name');
```

map function of arrays

```
 var names= jsonobject.jsontest.map(function(item,index){
     return item["name"];
    })
```

Comment: pluck is deprecated in lo dash but you can use map in the same way so I would show `_.map` to replace your `_.pluck`

Answer (score 1):

you can use forEach method of javascript

```
var arr=jsonobject.jsontest;
arr.forEach(function(item, index){console.log(item.name)})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll just throw in here the simple JavaScript solution:
First  you might have to parse out this JSON since you have angular you can safely parse with `angular.fromJson(obj)'

`var jsonObj = angular.fromJson(jsonobject)`

Then

`var nameArray = [];`

sets the empty array where you can store the names or you can use map but not as simple.

`for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.jsonsontest.length; i++){`

sets up for loop..

`nameArray.push( jsonObj.jsonsontest[i].name);`

adds elements

`}`
 
closes a for loop...

Thats the long walk through step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this, use `jsonobject.jsontest` to resolve your problem

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  var jsonobject = {
    "jsontest": [{
        "name": "firstnamevalue",
        "firstkey": "firstvalue"

    }, {
        "name": "secondnamevalue",
        "secondkey": "secondvalue",
        "thirdkey": false
    }, {
        "name": "thirdnamevalue",
        "fourthkey": null
    }],
    "fifthkey": "testvalues"
};
  
  $scope.results = jsonobject.jsontest.map(function(item,index){
     return item["name"];

    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  {{results}}
</div>
```

Comment: angular code completely superfluous and only pollutes the answer

Comment: Also if your going to show the HTML maybe just use `<span ng-repeat='person in jsonObj.jsonTest'>` `{{person.name}}`</span>